ARM templates: The resource is not defined in the template
Can anyone help me with the issue I am having when I am trying to deploy multiple resources via ARM templates?
Since I want to deploy resources which are scoped on different levels, I am using nested ARM templates. The structure of resources I want to deploy is like below.

I got an below error when I tried to deploy ARM templates from Azure CLI.
{"code": "InvalidTemplate", "target": "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/deploymentResourceGroupNetwork", "message": "Deployment template validation failed: 'The resource 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{myStorageAccountName}' is not defined in the template. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-syntax for usage details.'.", "additionalInfo": [{"type": "TemplateViolation", "info": {"lineNumber": 0, "linePosition": 0, "path": ""}}]}

I found a solution to the following similar question, but I wasn't sure if it applied to my case.
Nested Arm Template with with multiple scopes
Here is my ARM template file, parameter file and command used in Azure CLI.
ARM template(nested_template.json)
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "env":{
            "type": "String",
            "defaultValue": "devl",
            "allowedValues": [
                "devl",
                "prod"
            ]
        },
        "resourceGroupNetwork": {
            "type": "String",
            "defaultValue": "resourceGroupNetwork_dev",
            "allowedValues": [
                "resourceGroupNetwork_dev",
                "resourceGroupNetwork_prod"
            ]
        },
        "resourceGroupOther": {
            "type": "String",
            "defaultValue": "resourceGroupOther_dev",
            "allowedValues": [
                "resourceGroupOther_dev",
                "resourceGroupOther_prod"
            ]
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "starageAccountsEnvSettings": {
            "devl": {
                "subscription": "{subscriptionId}",
                "resouceGroupName": "[parameters('resourceGroupOther')]",
                "instanceName": "{instanceName}"
            },
            "prod": {
                "subscription": "{subscriptionId}",
                "resouceGroupName": "[parameters('resourceGroupOther')]",
                "instanceName": "{instanceName}"
            }
        },
        "privateEndpointsStrageBlobEnvSetting": {
            "devl": {
                "subscription": "{subscriptionId}",
                "resouceGroupName": "[parameters('resourceGroupNetwork')]",
                "instanceName": "{instanceName}",
                "networkInterfaceName": "{nicName}",
                "virtualNetworks": "{vNetName}",
                "subnets": "{subnetsName}"
            },
            "prod": {
                "subscription": "{subscriptionId}",
                "resouceGroupName": "[parameters('resourceGroupNetwork')]",
                "instanceName": "{instanceName}",
                "networkInterfaceName": "{nicName}",
                "virtualNetworks": "{vNetName}",
                "subnets": "{subnetsName}"
            }
        },
        "privateEndpointsStrageFilesEnvSetting": {
            "devl": {
                "subscription": "{subscriptionId}",
                "resouceGroupName": "[parameters('resourceGroupNetwork')]",
                "instanceName": "{instanceName}",
                "networkInterfaceName": "{nicName}",
                "virtualNetworks": "{vNetName}",
                "subnets": "{subnetsName}"
            },
            "prod": {
                "subscription": "{subscriptionId}",
                "resouceGroupName": "[parameters('resourceGroupNetwork')]",
                "instanceName": "{instanceName}",
                "networkInterfaceName": "{nicName}",
                "virtualNetworks": "{vNetName}",
                "subnets": "{subnetsName}"
            }
        }
    },
    "resources": [
      {
        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
        "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
        "subscriptionId": "[variables('starageAccountsEnvSettings')[parameters('env')].subscription]",
        "resourceGroup": "[variables('starageAccountsEnvSettings')[parameters('env')].resouceGroupName]",
        "name": "deploymentResourceGroupOther",
        "properties": {
          "mode": "Incremental",
          "template": {
            "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
            "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
            "resources": [
                {
                    "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
                    "apiVersion": "2023-05-01",
                    "name": "[variables('starageAccountsEnvSettings')[parameters('env')].instanceName]",
                    "location": "eastus2",
                    "tags": {},
                    "sku": {
                        "name": "Standard_ZRS",
                        "tier": "Standard"
                    },
                    "kind": "StorageV2",
                    "properties": {
                        "dnsEndpointType": "Standard",
                        "defaultToOAuthAuthentication": true,
                        "publicNetworkAccess": "Disabled",
                        "allowCrossTenantReplication": false,
                        "minimumTlsVersion": "TLS1_2",
                        "allowBlobPublicAccess": false,
                        "allowSharedKeyAccess": true,
                        "largeFileSharesState": "Enabled",
                        "networkAcls": {
                            "bypass": "AzureServices",
                            "virtualNetworkRules": [],
                            "ipRules": [],
                            "defaultAction": "Deny"
                        },
                        "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": true,
                        "encryption": {
                            "requireInfrastructureEncryption": false,
                            "services": {
                                "file": {
                                    "keyType": "Account",
                                    "enabled": true
                                },
                                "table": {
                                    "keyType": "Account",
                                    "enabled": true
                                },
                                "queue": {
                                    "keyType": "Account",
                                    "enabled": true
                                },
                                "blob": {
                                    "keyType": "Account",
                                    "enabled": true
                                }
                            },
                            "keySource": "Microsoft.Storage"
                        },
                        "accessTier": "Hot"
                   }
                },
                {
                    "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices",
                    "apiVersion": "2023-05-01",
                    "name": "[concat(variables('starageAccountsEnvSettings')[parameters('env')].instanceName, '/default')]",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('starageAccountsEnvSettings')[parameters('env')].instanceName)]"
                    ],
                    "sku": {
                        "name": "Standard_ZRS",
                        "tier": "Standard"
                    },
                    "properties": {
                        "containerDeleteRetentionPolicy": {
                            "enabled": true,
                            "days": 7
                        },
                        "cors": {
                            "corsRules": []
                        },
                        "deleteRetentionPolicy": {
                            "allowPermanentDelete": false,
                            "enabled": true,
                            "days": 7
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/fileServices",
                    "apiVersion": "2023-05-01",
                    "name": "[concat(variables('starageAccountsEnvSettings')[parameters('env')].instanceName, '/default')]",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('starageAccountsEnvSettings')[parameters('env')].instanceName)]"
                    ],
                    "sku": {
                        "name": "Standard_ZRS",
                        "tier": "Standard"
                    },
                    "properties": {
                        "protocolSettings": {
                            "smb": {}
                        },
                        "cors": {
                            "corsRules": []
                        },
                        "shareDeleteRetentionPolicy": {
                            "enabled": true,
                            "days": 7
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/privateEndpointConnections",
                    "apiVersion": "2023-05-01",
                    "name": "[concat(variables('starageAccountsEnvSettings')[parameters('env')].instanceName, '/', variables('starageAccountsEnvSettings')[parameters('env')].instanceName, '-strageAccounts')]",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('starageAccountsEnvSettings')[parameters('env')].instanceName)]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "privateEndpoint": {},
                        "privateLinkServiceConnectionState": {
                            "status": "Approved",
                            "description": "Auto-Approved",
                            "actionRequired": "None"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/queueServices",
                    "apiVersion": "2023-05-01",
                    "name": "[concat(variables('starageAccountsEnvSettings')[parameters('env')].instanceName, '/default')]",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('starageAccountsEnvSettings')[parameters('env')].instanceName)]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "cors": {
                            "corsRules": []
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/tableServices",
                    "apiVersion": "2023-05-01",
                    "name": "[concat(variables('starageAccountsEnvSettings')[parameters('env')].instanceName, '/default')]",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('starageAccountsEnvSettings')[parameters('env')].instanceName)]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "cors": {
                            "corsRules": []
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
        "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
        "name": "deploymentResourceGroupNetwork",
        "subscriptionId": "[variables('privateEndpointsStrageBlobEnvSetting')[parameters('env')].subscription]",
        "resourceGroup": "[variables('privateEndpointsStrageBlobEnvSetting')[parameters('env')].resouceGroupName]",
        "properties": {
          "mode": "Incremental",
          "template": {
            "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
            "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
            "resources": [
                {
                    "type": "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints",
                    "apiVersion": "2024-01-01",
                    "name": "[variables('privateEndpointsStrageBlobEnvSetting')[parameters('env')].instanceName]",
                    "location": "eastus2",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[resourceId(variables('starageAccountsEnvSettings')[parameters('env')].subscription, variables('starageAccountsEnvSettings')[parameters('env')].resouceGroupName, 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('starageAccountsEnvSettings')[parameters('env')].instanceName)]"
                    ],
                    "tags": {},
                    "properties": {
                        "privateLinkServiceConnections": [
                            {
                                "name": "[variables('privateEndpointsStrageBlobEnvSetting')[parameters('env')].instanceName]",
                                "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints', variables('privateEndpointsStrageBlobEnvSetting')[parameters('env')].instanceName), concat('/privateLinkServiceConnections/', variables('privateEndpointsStrageBlobEnvSetting')[parameters('env')].instanceName))]",
                                "properties": {
                                    "privateLinkServiceId": "[resourceId(variables('starageAccountsEnvSettings')[parameters('env')].subscription, variables('starageAccountsEnvSettings')[parameters('env')].resouceGroupName, 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('starageAccountsEnvSettings')[parameters('env')].instanceName)]",
                                    "groupIds": [
                                        "blob"
                                    ],
                                    "privateLinkServiceConnectionState": {
                                        "status": "Approved",
                                        "description": "Auto-Approved",
                                        "actionsRequired": "None"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "manualPrivateLinkServiceConnections": [],
                        "customNetworkInterfaceName": "[variables('privateEndpointsStrageBlobEnvSetting')[parameters('env')].networkInterfaceName]",
                        "subnet": {
                            "id": "[concat(variables('privateEndpointsStrageBlobEnvSetting')[parameters('env')].instanceName, '/subnets/', variables('privateEndpointsStrageBlobEnvSetting')[parameters('env')].subnets)]"
                        },
                        "ipConfigurations": [],
                        "customDnsConfigs": []
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints",
                    "apiVersion": "2024-01-01",
                    "name": "[variables('privateEndpointsStrageFilesEnvSetting')[parameters('env')].instanceName]",
                    "location": "eastus2",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[resourceId(variables('starageAccountsEnvSettings')[parameters('env')].subscription, variables('starageAccountsEnvSettings')[parameters('env')].resouceGroupName, 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('starageAccountsEnvSettings')[parameters('env')].instanceName)]"
                    ],
                    "tags": {},
                    "properties": {
                        "privateLinkServiceConnections": [
                            {
                                "name": "[variables('privateEndpointsStrageFilesEnvSetting')[parameters('env')].instanceName]",
                                "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints', variables('privateEndpointsStrageFilesEnvSetting')[parameters('env')].instanceName), concat('/privateLinkServiceConnections/', variables('privateEndpointsStrageFilesEnvSetting')[parameters('env')].instanceName))]",
                                "properties": {
                                    "privateLinkServiceId": "[resourceId(variables('starageAccountsEnvSettings')[parameters('env')].subscription, variables('starageAccountsEnvSettings')[parameters('env')].resouceGroupName, 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('starageAccountsEnvSettings')[parameters('env')].instanceName)]",
                                    "groupIds": [
                                        "file"
                                    ],
                                    "privateLinkServiceConnectionState": {
                                        "status": "Approved",
                                        "description": "Auto-Approved",
                                        "actionsRequired": "None"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "manualPrivateLinkServiceConnections": [],
                        "customNetworkInterfaceName": "[variables('privateEndpointsStrageFilesEnvSetting')[parameters('env')].networkInterfaceName]",
                        "subnet": {
                            "id": "[concat(variables('privateEndpointsStrageFilesEnvSetting')[parameters('env')].instanceName, '/subnets/', variables('privateEndpointsStrageFilesEnvSetting')[parameters('env')].subnets)]"
                        },
                        "ipConfigurations": [],
                        "customDnsConfigs": []
                    }
                },   
                {
                    "type": "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints/privateDnsZoneGroups",
                    "apiVersion": "2024-01-01",
                    "name": "privatelink.file.core.windows.net/default",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[resourceId(variables('privateEndpointsStrageFilesEnvSetting')[parameters('env')].subscription, variables('privateEndpointsStrageFilesEnvSetting')[parameters('env')].resouceGroupName,'Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints', variables('privateEndpointsStrageFilesEnvSetting')[parameters('env')].instanceName)]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "privateDnsZoneConfigs": [
                            {
                                "properties": {
                                    "privateDnsZoneId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', variables('privateEndpointsStrageBlobEnvSetting')[parameters('env')].subscription, '/resourceGroups/', variables('privateEndpointsStrageBlobEnvSetting')[parameters('env')].resouceGroupName, '/providers/Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones/privatelink.file.core.windows.net')]"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
                
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }

parameter file(template_parameter.json)
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "env": {
            "value": "devl"
        },
        "resourceGroupNetwork": {
            "value": "{resourceGroupNetworkName}"
        },
        "resourceGroupOther": {
            "value": "{resourceGroupOtherName}"
        }
    }
}

deploy command
az deployment group create 
    --resource-group {resouceGroupName} 
    --template-file ".\nested_template.json" 
    --parameters "@.\template_parameter.json"



ARM templates: The resource is not defined in the template Issue

As per the error the description it seems you declared the incorrect info related to the storage account name where you need to make the changes in "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{myStorageAccountName}".
I tried a template where I mentioned the resource as per the configuration and rewrite it and able to provision the configuration youre looking for.
nested_templete.json
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "storageAccountName": {
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Name of the Storage Account"
            }
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "String",
            "defaultValue": "eastus",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Location for all resources"
            }
        },
        "resourceGroupNetwork": {
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Resource group name for the virtual network"
            }
        },
        "resourceGroupStorage": {
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Resource group name for the storage account"
            }
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
            "name": "nestedStorageDeployment",
            "resourceGroup": "[parameters('resourceGroupStorage')]",
            "properties": {
                "mode": "Incremental",
                "template": {
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "resources": [
                        {
                            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
                            "apiVersion": "2023-05-01",
                            "name": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
                            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                            "sku": {
                                "name": "Standard_LRS"
                            },
                            "kind": "StorageV2",
                            "properties": {
                                "accessTier": "Hot"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
            "name": "nestedNetworkDeployment",
            "resourceGroup": "[parameters('resourceGroupNetwork')]",
            "properties": {
                "mode": "Incremental",
                "template": {
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "resources": [
                        {
                            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
                            "apiVersion": "2021-02-01",
                            "name": "myVnet",
                            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                            "properties": {
                                "addressSpace": {
                                    "addressPrefixes": [
                                        "10.0.0.0/16"
                                    ]
                                },
                                "subnets": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "default",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "addressPrefix": "10.0.0.0/24"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}


template_parameter.json:
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "storageAccountName": {
            "value": "vkdsbbbstorageaccount123"
        },
        "location": {
            "value": "eastus"
        },
        "resourceGroupNetwork": {
            "value": "demoNetworkvkResourceGroup"
        },
        "resourceGroupStorage": {
            "value": "demoStoragevkResourceGroup"
        }
    }
}

Deployment:


refer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.storage/storageaccounts?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template
